# How to insert a List<Class> into a Map<String, dynamic> in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

My problem is that I have a list of the following class:

```
class ingreso_Egreso_Dummy{
  int tipo;
  String monto;
  String moneda;
  String descripcion;
}
```

then I want to insert the data into a Map which later will be converted into a json and which I am creating like this:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> body;
        body = {
          "Cod_Prom": "01",
          "CodCli": "003526",
          "Status": _index_status.toString(),
          "NOMBRE": controller_nombre.text,
          "APELLIDOS": controller_apellidos.text,
          "solicitud":[{
            "Cod_Solicit": 1.toString(),
            "Fecha": DateFormat("y-d-M").format(DateTime.now()),
            "Status_Solicit": "E",}],
          "prestamo":[{
            "Monto_Solicit":controller_monto_solic.text,
            "Plazo":controller_plazo.text,
            "Cod_TipoPlazo":_index_tipoplazo.toString(),
            "Nombre_Resp":controller_nombreresp.text,
            "Telf_Resp":controller_telefonoresp.text,}],
          "Ingresos": [{
    //// here I want create a loop that returns a map for each value
   //// of the list like this:

   //// "Descripcion": Listaingresos[i].descripcion;

            })
          }]
        };
```

Every help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: look at Map.fromIterable()

Comment: I tried but it returns a instance of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// camelCaseStyle is a standard for class names for Dart     
class IngresoEgresoDummy { 
  int tipo;
  String monto;
  String moneda;
  String descripcion;
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      'tipo': tipo,
      'monto': monto,
      'monedo': moneda,
      'descripcion': descripcion
    };
  }
}
```

and after that

```
List<IngresoEgresoDummy> listaingresos= List();

Map<String, dynamic> body = {
// all your params
  "Ingresos": listaingresos.map((ingreso) => ingreso.toJson()).toList()
// all your params
};
```

Comment: I had find a way to do it but yours look much cleaner I'll leave it here:

`"Egresos": [
        for(ingreso_Egreso_Dummy i in egresos_Dummies){
          "tipo":i.tipo.toString(),
          "monto":i.monto,
          "moneda":i.moneda,
          "descripcion":i.descripcion
        }
      ],`

Thanks for your, answer, just edit a letter, bad written in 'monedo' there goes an 'a' but I'll accept your answer